# Okay to open modal via anchor with valid href?

Tags: accessibility

We have a bunch of modal dialogs in our application. When a user clicks a button it fetches the modal content from the server and displays it to the user. The way that it is structured, in order to fetch the content from the server, the button is nested inside of a form tag with an action specifying the URL to fetch the modal from. Because we can't nest form tags, this severely limits where we can place modal toggles without doing a lot of CSS trickery.

So, I'm wondering if it is acceptable from an accessibility standpoint to use an anchor tag with a valid href to display the modal. We'll intercept the click with JavaScript, fetch the content via ajax, and display it on the modal. If JavaScript isn't working or the user opens the link in a new tab, they'll still see the modal content, just with a sparse layout.

Is this a reasonable and accessible approach to take? It seems like as long as the anchor has a valid href it should be fine, and provides a tiny bit more flexibility to the user if they want to open up the link in a new tab.

Comment: It would be cool if you can update this question without so much technical explanations and with focus only to the Usability part. (Downvoted it untill then)
Answer to your question could be: If you can avoid modals, if this is necessity than you can place nexto to "Links" aka "A hrefs" appropriate icons so user understands what will happen upon clicking the link.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your request. What technical detail is the problem here? I was trying to provide useful context.

Comment: User experience in a sense you have describe it is not connected to server, fetsching, intercepting click with JS events and so on. I have edited your question. This is what you were asking, right?

Comment: @xul that is the basic question I'm trying to ask, but I think the technical details are important. A large part of the question is how this might impact a disabled user with a screen reader, which does involve the lower level details.

Comment: Still all technical matters should be transfered to development stack. UX Accessibility points here is that it doesnt matter for the user what happens in the background. As long you have signalised your links properly (can be with icons), if you have sufficient color contrast, naming, tap area (48 x 48) youll be fine.. All other technical info does not belong here.. I think you would get better answers if questions is reshaped